# External interrupt code for PIC18LF47k40 not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplabx, gpio-external-interrupt

I wrote a external interrupt code for [PIC18LF47k40](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18LF27_47K40-Data-Sheet-40001844E.pdf) on MPLAB X IDE to toggle a LED when rising edge will be occurred.  It is not working, but the same type code for [PIC18F452](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/39564c.pdf) is working fine, only I modified the Register. Can you please help me why my below code for PIC18LF47K0 is not working?

below my code:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic18lf47k40.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
     TRISDbits.TRISD6=0;             //RD pin as output declaration
     PORTDbits.RD6=1;                

     TRISBbits.TRISB2=1;        /* Make INT2 pin as an input pin*/
     ANSELBbits.ANSELB2 = 0;        //making digital input
     INTCONbits.GIE=1;            /* Enable Global Interrupt*/  
     INTCONbits.INT2EDG=1;      /* Set Interrupt on rising Edge*/
     PIE0bits.INT2IE=1;        /* Enable INT2 external interrupt*/
     PIR0bits.INT2IF=0;           // Clear the interrupt flag
    
while(1)
{
}

}


void __interrupt() isr(void)
{         
        LATbits.RD6^=0;    //making togle RD6 pin    
        PIR0bits.INT2IF=0;  // Clear the interrupt fla          
}
```

Comment: Don't double include the header: `#include <xc.h>
#include <pic18lf47k40.h>`. Just use `xc.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code isn't toggling anything:

```c
LATbits.RD6^=0;    //making togle RD6 pin
```

The bitwise XOR works as follows:

```
  1100
^ 1010
  ----
  0110
```

As you can see, XOR-ing with 0 will simply retain the initial value.

You have to change that line to one of the following:

```c
LATbits.RD6 = !LATbits.RD6;
LATbits.RD6 ^= 1;
```

If `RD6` is a 1-bit element of a bitfield, I would prefer the first line. It makes little sense to use bitwise operators on a single bit.

Comment: Nice. It's been a while that I wrote PIC code but I think the preferred way was: LATbits.RD6 = ~LATbits.RD6;

Comment: @Rodo Yes, for this purpose I would prefer bitwise NOT over bitwise XOR. But for a single bit I'd still choose boolean NOT.